# Find today's date in a .txt file and print line?

Tags: c, date

I have a small problem working with dates, whereas I need to print all lines in a `.txt` file containing the user's current date.

Here's my code:

```
//My function
int search(FILE *fp, char * str)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("fp1","w");
    char s[10],c;
    int len = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;
    int d;
    int seek = fseek(fp, 0, 0);
    c = fgetc(fp);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
        {
            s[i] = '\0';
            i = 0;
            if (strcmp(s, str) == 0)
            {
                while (c = fgetc(fp) != '\n')
                {
                    fseek(fp, -2L, 1);
                    d = ftell(fp);
                }
                while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n')
                {
                    fputc(c, fp1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            s[i] = c;
            i++;
        }
        c = fgetc(fp);
    }
    return 1;
}

//int main function callback
            printf("\n\nTasks due today("__DATE__"): \n");
            FILE *tasks = fopen("tasks.txt", "r+");
            search(tasks, __DATE__);
            fclose(tasks);
```

Any idea on how to get this working?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to read the file a line at a time?  If so it will be easier and more straightforward to call `fgets`.  Also 10 is probably much too small for `s[]`.

Comment: Not at all sure what `fp1` is for.

Comment: What is not working ? Does the program compile ? Does it compile and run ? If it runs what is the output ? What do you expect your program to print ? What is the input file ?

Comment: Define _the user's current date_. Are you sure that `__DATE__` does what you think ?

Comment: fgets or getline ==> strstr

Comment: Maybe you should use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) and [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) which would greatly simplify your `search` function..

Comment: @MichaelWalz It compiles, runs, but it doesn't do what it should. I want it to print the whole line containing a certain date which is the user's date. Example: The file contains May 10 2016, today's date is also May 10 2016, I need it to print everyline containing this date to the user's screen.

Comment: @JadLattouf look at my previous comment. Your search function should be at most 6-7 lines long.

Comment: The string "May 10 2016" is 11 characters long.  With a newline and a nul character terminator that's 13 characters.  So *if* your program is even reading whole lines into `s[]` (which I doubt), it's overflowing that array, so it's definitely not working.

Comment: I suggest you tackle this in smaller steps.  See if you can write a program to just read lines and print them.  Once you've got that working well, you can add the step that decides whether to print the line or not based on what it contains.

Comment: @SteveSummit I tried allocating more than 10 characters, and it's still not working. That's not our problem, the problem is that I can't find a proper way to do this, if you can give it a try.

Comment: @JadLattouf do what SteveSummit suggests. That's definitely the way to proceed.

Comment: Note that `__DATE__` is at the time of compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int search(FILE *fp, const char *str){
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("fp1","w");
    if(!fp || !fp1 || !str || !*str)
        return 0;

    char line[128];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)){
        if(strstr(line, str)){
            fputs(line, fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    return 1;
}

int main(void){
    printf("\n\nTasks due today(\"%s\"): \n", __DATE__);
    FILE *tasks = fopen("tasks.txt", "r");
    search(tasks, __DATE__);//Note that __DATE__ is at the time of compilation.
    fclose(tasks);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @JadLattouf make date string instead of `__DATE__`

Comment: _doesn't work_ is not exactly a description that helps us to resolve your problem.